# How do i retrieve information from firebase Authorization

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have created a profile page that retrieves  information from Firebase *realtime database*
but now I came to know it is not safe to store it in realtime database so i have decided to keep it in auth itself but idk how to retrieve the code from it
this is how i created profile page

```
ublic class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private String userID;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        final TextView Username=findViewById(R.id.Username1);
        final TextView email=findViewById(R.id.emailadress);
        final TextView Password=findViewById(R.id.passwordd);
        user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        userID=user.getUid();
        reference.child("Driver").child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull  DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Users usersnapshot=snapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                if(usersnapshot!=null){
                    String username=usersnapshot.getUsername();
                    String Email=usersnapshot.getMail();
                    String password=usersnapshot.getPassword();
                    Username.setText(username);
                    email.setText(Email);
                    Password.setText(password);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull  DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the information you are looking for. Firebase Authentication only stores a small set of information about a user, and for example:

- Firebase will not be able to return you the password of the user - as that'd be a huge security risk.
- Firebase does not have a username property, although it does have a display name, which might be what you're looking for.

You can get the information for the current user by looking get:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()
```

Also see the documentation on [getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

---

If you want to store **additional** information about the user, you **can** store that in your own database under the UID as you did before.

You just should *never* store the credentials in the way you did, as storing passwords in cleartext is one of the worst security risks you can inflict on your users. See for example: [Why shouldn't I store passwords in plaintext?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120540/why-shouldnt-i-store-passwords-in-plaintext), but also many more from [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=storing+passwords+in+cleartext).